# How to get the filepath of a ZipFile object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, zip, filepath, python-zipfile

If I have a `zipfile.ZipFile` object, how can I determine the file path of the zip file from the object?

```
a = zipfile.ZipFile('C:\\path\\zipfile.zip')

a.get_file_path()
```

where `get_file_path()` should return `'C:\\path\\zipfile.zip'`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access it using `filename` attribute:

```
a.filename
```